# AWS - check cost of CloudWatch (itself)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cost-explorer

I want to check the usage of cloud watch and how much it costs me per day/month

but I don't mean the basic output of cost explorer but detailed output of all the "components" i got there and how much I pay for each one

**I can see in cost explorer that cloud watch costs me each month** X$ but I want to see what this X consists of, like 0.5$ for metric Z, 5$ for group log Y , etc.

Help please =)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Console does give you bill by usage type. You can correlate usage type to logs, metrics, etc. The steps to see the bill for usage type are:

1. Log in to your AWS console.
2. Go to `Billing` by searching or navigating from services.
3. Click on `Bills` on the left navigation pane.
4. Select the month from the drop down.
5. Expand CloudWatch from the `Bill details by service`
6. You should see list of $ by Usage type:
   [image]

The same can be achieved from AWS Cost Explorer too by grouping by Usage Type/ Usage Type Group.

Comment: I need it in more detail - i can see how much i pay for metrics, logs , etc. but i want also to see what metrics its include and so on...